# AWS Device Farm - extra data path in script

Tags: appium

My Appium script perfectly working on local but moving to aws device farm, returns parsing error because of one class file.
I am trying to import data from an excel file within this class file. I think error because of the path of excel file.

I upload the data excel file as extra data in aws but i can’t find out the location.

```
public static void changeCity() throws InterruptedException{
try{
    File src = new File("data1.xls");
    Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(src);
    Sheet sh1 = wb.getSheet(0);
    Sheet bugzillaUpdation = wb.getSheet("UtilityCredentials");
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

---

@jmp

I used junit and put the location as 
`File src = new File("/acme-android-appium/src/test/resources/data1.xls");`

I am not clear about the XML file you said above. Can you please explain how can we find file in my script.

Please take a look at the attached image.

[image: project explorer]

Answer (score 1):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

To read a `.xlsx` or `.csv` file the following two approaches can be used:

1. Make sure the excel file is placed under `src/test/resources/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx/csv`
2. This will place the file in the test jar file under the `com` folder.
3. Once that is confirmed you should be able to read the file using one of the two code snippets below:

Without any external libraries:

```
java.net.URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx");
File file = new File(resource.toURI());
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

OR

If you are using Apache POI APIs for reading excel files:

```
InputStream ins = getClass().getResourceAsStream(“/com/yourexcelfile.xlsx”);
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ins);
sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(1);
ins.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try putting the file in the  src/test/java/resources/ of the project? That way it would be built with the jar and device farm may have reference to it then.

[update]

Tried this myself with the example project from awslabs github page[1]. I also optionally created a testng.xml file that contained this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="test">
        <classes>
            <class name="file.FindFile"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

This file is located in /Referenceapp-Appium-Test/src/test/resources/testng.xml and is referenced from the pom.xml using this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The testng.xml is used here to only run the specific test and not all the of the tests in the example project. It is optional and here for FYI knowledge.

I then created a test.csv file in the same directory and created a new package 'file' with a test class inside of it 'FindFile':

```
package file;

import java.io.File;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Pages.BasePage;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;

public class FindFile extends BasePage {
     protected FindFile(AppiumDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

     @Test
    public static void changeCity() throws InterruptedException{
            try{
                File src = new File("/Referenceapp-Appium-Test/src/test/resources/test.csv");
                System.out.println("File found!!!");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
}
```

So when I executed this it in device farm with a random apk I had it only executed the tests inside of the FindFile.java. When I looked at the appium java output I seen my println there so that is how I know it works.

```
[TestNG] RUNNING: Suite: "Command line test" containing "1" Tests (config: null)
[TestNG] INVOKING: "Command line test" - file.FindFile.changeCity()
[Invoker 1121172875] Invoking file.FindFile.changeCity
File found!!!
[TestNG] PASSED: "Command line test" - file.FindFile.changeCity() finished in 35 ms
===== Invoked methods
    FindFile.changeCity()[pri:0, instance:null]  <static>
=====
Creating /tmp/scratchLT6UDz.scratch/resultsm_f_bN/Command line suite/Command line test.html
Creating /tmp/scratchLT6UDz.scratch/resultsm_f_bN/Command line suite/Command line test.xml
PASSED: changeCity
```

Hope that Helps

Best Regards

James

[1] https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app

Comment: File src = new File("/Referenceapp-Appium-Test/src/test/resources/test.csv"); This not works for me. File path is still error.

Comment: Silly question but you added a test.csv to that directory right?

Comment: Could you provide me with more information about how you followed what I did?

Comment: Please check the post including screen shot. I post the comment as answer.

Comment: I haven't tested this idea yet, however if this is a maven project and the test get zipped up and uploaded why not just include the extra files with the zipped test package? It should be fairly easy to write maven plugin that adds this to it. Before writing it just try adding the file and accessing it in Device Farm.